# Where should navigation buttons in panel be located?

Tags: navigation, dashboard, footers, panel

Currently the action/navigation buttons of my UI project is in the panel-footer (see screenshot), and I'm wondering if that is an intuitive place or if they fit better in the header. Most panels are within the size of screen so no scrolling is required. The header always requires the title so its unlogical to put the buttons in there. Whats your opinion? Does this make sense?

[image: dashboard navigation]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your navigation buttons in the **bottom right** of your panel.

Consider the Gutenberg diagram;

> When the user reaches the lower right portion of the page there is a
>   break in the reading or “page scan” process and the user will need to
>   take an action. This is the perfect spot to insert call-to-action such
>   as buttons, links, forms, video, etc.

Source: [The Gutenberg Diagram in Web Design](https://medium.com/user-experience-3/the-gutenberg-diagram-in-web-design-e5347c172627)

Also consider the meaning of back and next in navigation. When progressing/completing, the general association is going right. The general association for going back/cancel is going left. So put your back button to the left of your next button.

[image: gutenberg diagram]

Comment: Great answer, I was about to post the same thing myself but you beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks, @JoelTebbett. I'm looking forward to the next time where you might beat me to it!